# Android Hidden Process

Tags: android, android-ndk

Android Services is listed in the Android Running services list , but creation of a process hidden from the Android running process List seems to be clumsy , i had tried making a FORK() using the JNI , were libc is included by , outcome was a crash .

So i want to know is it possible to start a hidden process , which is not listed in the PROCESS LIST .

Answer (score 3):

> So i want to know is it possible to start a hidden process , which is not listed in the PROCESS LIST

Fortunately, no, except perhaps by writing your own custom firmware.

Comment: custom firmware is a distant solution ....if at least code injection can be done to any other process like MESSAGE APP or CALLER APP so that i can run another process as a subsidiary to these apps can actually hide others from users perspective...